# How to enable Salesforce Wave functionality in dev org?

Tags: salesforce1-platform, analytics-cloud, einstein-analytics

There is no proper documentation around it , no resources and no links in Dev org to see what is Wave. I would like to get started and see how it is better than any other cloud analytic tools. Any pointers please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All explained well in this blog - 
https://nextgensalesforce.wordpress.com/2015/09/28/creating-your-very-own-salesforce-wave-application/

**From link-**

Step 1: As first steps you need to sign up for a WAVE development org. (P.S If you’re existing developer org has Analytics licenses you can jump to Step 3)

Step 2: You can register for your very own WAVE developer Org here – https://developer.salesforce.com/promotions/orgs/Wave-DF15-DE

@@@ Great Job on creating the WAVE developer Org. @@@

Step 3: Now click on the link – https://startsurfingthewave.herokuapp.com/actions/enablement

Step 4: You’ll have to sign in into the developer org created in Step 1 and click Allow.

[image]

Step 5: Click on Go to My Org

[image]

Hurray.. Now you get the Salesforce Analytics Page on your own developer org – how cool is that :)

[image]

Step 6: Click on Enable Analytics

Step 7: On the Previous Page click on Verify Setup and Assign Permissions

[image]

Step 8: Once this setup is complete, you’ll see Analytics in the App picker. If you don’t refresh your page.

[image]

Step 9: Select Analytics.

Answer (score 3):

You can't add analytics cloud to your dev org at the moment.

The help contains some basics - just search for "analytics cloud", and if you have access to a premier training org there are the white (20 mins) and green (6 hours) belt training videos.

If you are a US based partner there are demo orgs available after you have completed white/green belt training, but these aren't available outside of the US.

Looks like a waiting game based on this thread in the official group : https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009MBPCA2&fId=0D53000001eyEcgCAE

Answer (score 3):

Now you can just go to this link 
[developer.salesforce.com/promotions/orgs/Wave-DF15-DE](https://developer.salesforce.com/promotions/orgs/Wave-DF15-DE)
Thanks to trailhead now I can learn and explore WAVE

Comment: This link does not work.

Comment: sorry Chris I have  edited try now

Comment: also you can  go through [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/wave_analytics_explorer/wave_analytics_basics/wave_start_surfing_the_wave)

Comment: This link WORKS for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to join the [Success Community Official Wave Group](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009MBP)
to get all the details and directly ask your questions to the product team.

there are few webinars scheduled and also it seems enabling wave for dev org is also in their roadmap..

Comment: Just curious to know, on your comment about Wave in Developer Edition - any official announcement from Salesforce.com on this?