# What is Salesforce Wave Analytics? What is the need for it?

Tags: analytics, einstein-analytics

I am newbie to "Wave Analytics" in Salesforce. I want to learn about Wave Analytics Components available in Salesforce version and its uses. There is no proper documentation around it. Where can i see the Wave Analytics in Salesforce org.

Can any one explain me about "What is Wave Analytics in salesforce and what is the use of it?". How can i enable 'Wave Analytics' in already created developer org.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wave analytics is a new cloud based analytic tool that will help you to create powerful reports and dashboards from your large amount of enterprise data .The data may be inside SFDC or may reside in your external system .

The best place to get started is using Trailhead .Below are some of Trailhead modules that will get you started .Also you will get a free developer instance for playing around

[Wave Basics](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/wave_analytics_basics)

[Wave Desktop Exploration](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/wave_desktop_exploration)

[Wave mobile Exploration](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/wave_mobile_exploration)

If you are working with salesforce as a partner then there are specific trainings you would like to get

1)White belt 
2)Green belt 
3)Brown belt

There are chatter groups on patner portal where you can find all helpful documentation .Once you complete Green belt you get a free org for practice .

Comment: Mohith - wouldn't the elevator pitch be "Wave Analytics" is SFDC's answer to Tableau?

Comment: @crop1645 I guess it's answer to all analytics tool available in market.The big advantage is its cloud and mobile enabled

Comment: I think the major advantage is that Wave Analytics works more seamlessly with Salesforce CRM data (since it is SFDC after all) rather than having a connector to/from Tableau and any other Analytics platform out there

Answer (score 2):

Please visit this link for Setting up the ORG for wave analytics.
This will give you step by step guid to set up wave.
[visit here](https://nextgensalesforce.wordpress.com/2015/09/28/creating-your-very-own-salesforce-wave-application/)

and also you can check this Q/A [check here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65038/how-to-enable-salesforce-wave-functionality-in-dev-org)

Comment: Hi, link in that says to create a new seperate org with Wave Analytics. Instead I want to enalbe 'Wave Analytics' in already created developer org.

Comment: Salesforce orgs don’t come with Wave Analytics by default. To get it, your org requires a separate Analytics Cloud Wave Platform license. Did you check this trailhead link for enabling https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/wave_analytics_basics/wave_set_up_wave#wave_enable_wave_analytics

Answer (score 2):

While working on both 'Report & Dashboard' and 'Wave-Analytics-Cloud', if I have to answer at very high level & really impacting features:

1. Analytics-cloud gives you feature of data massaging (extract, merge, conditioning, transformation, appending, etc.). Example, how do you merge two different Objects and twist it to generate your view/report.
2. Integration to external Data Sources. With 'Report & Dashboard' we had to export Salesforce data to a data warehouse and marry it with other data to generate the reports. But, now, with Analytics-cloud, I can do this with Salesforce Analytics-Cloud.
3. Analytics-Cloud gives you a platform to store your 'transformed' data from where end-users can create Reports or Dashboard. This 'transformed' data could be seen as if you have your data in a classical database. (not exactly but could be seen as).