# How to get Analytic s licenses for my developer edition?

Tags: einstein-analytics

I am the beginner to "Wave Analytic's" in sales force. I need to learn what is "Wave Analytic's" in salesforce, where we will use "Wave Analytic's" and why we use "Wave Analytic's" in salesforce. Is it possible to use wave analytics in my edition. How to get Analytic s licenses for my developer edition.. can any one tell me solutions for these questions..

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65038/how-to-enable-salesforce-wave-functionality-in-dev-org please check link

Answer (score 2):

The best way to deal with this is look at the trailhead module as that allows you to sign up for a Wave Analytics Developer org.

[Trailead Wave Analytics](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/trail/wave_analytics_explorer)

It is not possible to get Wave added to an existing developer edition as this is not supported by Salesforce, so you would have to sign up for one of the specific Wave Developer orgs.